# Does the new performance slider in Windows 10 insider builds work?

Tags: windows-10, power, windows-insider

When I left click on the battery icon in the task tray of Windows 10 Insider Preview, there is a new slider control labelled "power mode".
I had read that this doesn't work, and is a GUI module only at this point and not yet wired up to true battery or performance toggles.
Is that true?  Or does it actually change things like processor speed etc?
I'm using Windows 10 Insider Build 16251_rs3_release.170721-2122.

Comment: It was just a trial GUI to begin with but it now seems to do something if you have the right CPU https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2017/04/18/introducing-power-throttling/#P42HFVd27eXmptdU.97